# In DataGridView how to enable and disable bitmap Image

Tags: c#

I have DataGridView with Four columns.
1st column contains "Text",
2nd, 3rd and 4rt column contains Bit Image.

Now this image are conditionally get rendered inside the columns and if condition is false it will contain "null" i.e. nothing in that column. However this blank column is part of Tab key, means when user navigate using Tab key in the grid, cursor traverse across all the column irrespective of column contains anything or not in it.

I would like to traverse cursor only to the column which contains value with in it. So how can I achieved this?

Following are the approaches I tried - 
1. I filled all the column with respective images by removing the condition. now all the columns have some image in it, but I am unable to Enable/Disable those image conditionally. and because of that this all images are actionable and user can perform the operation which it should not. And when I applied Visible true/False so that it will apply across all rows for that column index and resultant the valid cell also invisible.
2. I placed button with in that column and tried to applied that bit image to that button and tried to enable/disable button as button has the property. but Bit Image is not getting applied to button and when I assign gridCell.value = btn; it will throw error since it is not text it is complete control. So not valid approach.
3. Using ProcessCmdKey() Method group, but not acceptable approach, though it has started performing as expected.

Please find the screen shot for more detail.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[Layout images and behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfYun.png)d0sAI.png

Comment: Just trying to figure out. Can u assign "read only" property to those column which u wanna avoid tab action and check.

Comment: Sorry to update the approach, I already did that and it was also not working.